# How to make a subset in Plotly

Tags: plotly, subset, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I wonder how I can show a bar chart of the stores and value, but only when indicator = Category 1?

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQEO9.png)

I have tried this:

subset = df[df['Indicator'].isin(['category 1'])]

fig = px.bar(df, x='Store', y=(subset), 'Value')
#fig.show()

Comment: Try this: `fig = px.bar(subset, x='Store', y='Value');fig.show()`